# Green Colors on profile have changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Don't know if it is just me, but **have the shades of green on user profiles (accepted answers, line borders, etc.) changed somehow?**

If we compare a screenshot from my main profile:

[image]

with one of my Meta profile:

[image]

We can see that the shades of green have been altered somehow. It is now more "opaque" than before. In fact, comparing the RGB values I get that previously (second pic) it was **[50,197,112]** and now (first pic) it is **[141,178,98]**.

This I only see on my TWP profile. *I checked on SO and the color there is like the second image*. However, checking my *Meta SE profile I see that the green color is like the first image* (the opaque version).

**Any explanation for this behavior?** I know it is somehow superfluous but my eye couldn't help from noticing it.

**Edit:** Derivated MetaSE [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305850/332286) I asked over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed now; see my [answer on your question on the network Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305882/115866).

Comment: Thanks, will do as soon as I get to my PC. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Not only are main and meta different, but this is a recent change on main (and Meta.SE).  Here's a [snapshot from the Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414025900/http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/325/monica-cellio?tab=topactivity):

[image: main site with correct green]

Comment: Indeed. Seems to me that the "old" green shade was more adequate to the site's color palette. I wrote a Meta SE question (as you already saw) to see if they have something else to add to this situation

Answer (score 2):

It's not just you, it's definitely a different shade of green.

[image]

Comment: Yup, same here. Question is, is this is a bug or a design change? The new green doesn't seem to fit in with the rest of the color scheme and just looks out of place to me.